# Is it possible to make two-way SSL asynchronous?

Tags: ssl, asynchronous, emq

Is it possible to make two-way SSL asynchronous?

After the client verifies the server ssl certificate is correct, it can establish a connection successfully and the client can start to publish messages. This process is like one-way SSL.

Then the server would check the client ssl certificate asynchronously. And during the checking time, the client could publish messages normally, and the server could process these messages and response ACK. Once the server asynchronously find something wrong with the client ssl certificate, then the server would terminate the connection with client.

Can such this requirement be achieved? If possible, how should I do?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The SSL handshake is already defined, and it says that if the server requests a certificate the client has to supply it right then before the handshake completes. You can't change that. *However* you can start the SSL session with server authentication only and upgrade it later on, by (1) invalidating the session, (2) changing the server's SSL configuration to request or require a client certificate at that point, and (3) initiating a new handshake. I wouldn't describe any of this as 'asynchronous'.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for you replay! Sounds like such this requirement is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server can request a client certificate inside the initial TLS handshake but not verify the client certificate inside the handshake, i.e. it is verified outside the TLS handshake. This method is in practice for example used to successfully establish a TLS connection only to send a useful error message to the client instead of just closing the connection.

Another method is have the initial TLS handshake without requesting a client certificate but later request it by doing a TLS renegotiation (or post-handshake in TLS 1.3, see comment from dave_thompson_085). This is for example used to request a client certificate only for specific resources - but in order to know which resource the client requested application data from the client need to be read first.

Comment: In 1.3 renegotiation no longer exists, but there is an optional feature (if extension 49) specifically for post-handshake client auth; see rfc8446 4.6.2.